# Is there a way to tell what a serverside redirect will finalize on?

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I've seen people use bitly links in their forum signatures in order to bring up images.
This was something new to me.
Is there a way for Javascript to determine if a bitly link (or any other serverside-redirecting link) forwards to **OR** generates an image?

Comment: can this link be followed with PSON? or... JSONP (am I saying it right?)

Comment: jsonp expects to get a chunk of text that looks like `<script>...</script>`. you can't simply point at any url and have it work as jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

This function will determine if a link is or forwards to an image

```
function isImageLink(uri,callback) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.onerror = function() {
       callback(false);        
    }
    img.onload = function() {
        callback(true);
    }
    img.src = uri
}
```

It needs to be called with a URL and a Callback like so:

```
isImageLink("http://bit.ly/SVIR5g",function(isImage){
    if(isImage) {
        console.log("Valid Image");                
    }
    else {
        console.log("Invalid Image");            
    }
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RLeRW/6/
​

Comment: this is beautiful. Thanks I'll be sure to try it out!

Comment: can I do the parellel for audio elements and video elements?

Comment: according to w3schools both <video> and <audio> tag support HTML event attributes (onload / onerror) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp, so it should be possible.. I guess you could use this method to also detect the type of link.. keep trying to load link until something returns valid.